# php-fpm writing huge log file

Tags: php, nginx

in `/usr/local/nginx/logs/` I have a huge `www.access.log` file.

It grows undefinitely (last time I truncated it was 3.5 GB) with a new log entry every time a php script is called.

Every line looks like this:

```
- -  21/Feb/2016:00:59:09 +0100 "GET /index.php" 200 /absoulute-path/index.php 10,373 1280 96,40%
```

The file is written by `php-fpm` process

Browsing thru the various configuration files (nginx, php.ini....) I cannot find the directive to write logs to that file.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the format and the informations provided in the sample log entry posted in the question **the huge log file has nothing** (directly) **to do with nginx nor with its configuration files**, despite it's located in `.../nginx/logs/`

That `....access.log` file is written by **php-fpm** worker processes when a specific option is set into php-fpm's configuration file `php-fpm.conf`

The file (on my server) is located into `/etc/`

At some point in the configuration file there is:

```
; The access log file
; Default: not set
; access.log = /usr/local/nginx/logs/$pool.access.log
```

By default that option is not set and should remain unset; as far as I know the log file it produces is used to test php-fpm proper operation.

If the line is uncommented by removing the semicolon...

```
; The access log file
; Default: not set
access.log = /usr/local/nginx/logs/$pool.access.log
```

...then a `.access.log` file prefixed with the pool name (`www` in the case exposed in the question) is generated. And it grows quickly as each time a php script is run due to a request a new log entry is appended.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the *nginx.conf* configuration file in this way:

```
server {
   (...)
   access_log off;
}
```

*nginx.conf* is located in */usr/local/nginx/conf*, */usr/local/etc/nginx* or */etc/nginx*

---

- See more [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html)

---

Edit: see also [How to disable Nginx logging](https://serverfault.com/questions/318574/how-to-disable-nginx-logging), [Disable access logging](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,38447,38449#msg-38449) and [ngx_http_log_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)

Comment: I have `access_log off;` in my configuration file (inside a `server` block, inside an `http` block). I'm sure the conf. file is the one loaded by trying `sudo nginx -t`. However the `www.access.log` is still growing...

Comment: Maybe you have another “user” config file? `access_log off` is in original config or it is added by you?

Comment: `access_log` is the original config file with some adjustments (nr. of workers, user/group of the workers, etc...) at the end per-virtual domain configuration files are included with `include sites_enabled` however `access.log` is never turned on. Furthermore the offending log file is not `access.log` but `www.access.log`. I also have smaller log files named `fpm-php.www.log` and `php-fpm.log` that I don't know where they come from (always in `/nginx/logs`). I'm not the one that made the initial setup of the server. I'm trying to tidy it up but I'm stuck on those log files...

Comment: I use also nginx but I'm not a real expert. I don't haave a _www.access_log_. If you don't find any useful info by google or by another comment/answer here, you can try a **disperate** `egrep -R /your/path -e www.access.log` to see where this logfile is defined... It is not a smart advice, but... it can work.

Comment: after desperate search found the directive for that log file into `/etc/php-fpm.conf` - thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

Disable this **is not a good practice** .

Those files can give your very sensitive and informative information about your site visitor .

You can make some changes to make log files take a smaller space and easy to maintain.

You can make **compression** , Log **Rotation** to avoid filing up disk space and manage your log files .

Please check this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps).

Comment: it is a good practice to know first why a log file is there and what configuration file tells nginx/php-fpm to write on it. then we may discuss whether the informaion on it is useful or not, log size and log rotation. The suggested link instructs to set `access_log off;` that I already did.